# React map is not rendering items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React is not rendering items on a map function.

```
<Tab eventKey="All" title="All">
  {this.state.todoData && this.state.todoData.length ? (
    this.state.todoData.map((item, index) => {
      return <span key={item.todoId}>{item.todoTitle}</span>;
    })
  ) : (
    <span>No item found</span>
  )}
</Tab>
```

Render function is not rendering items or No Item found.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `render function is not rendering items or No Item found` ....is it rendering the tab?

Comment: It is rendering Tab and nothing in it. Just blank space.

Comment: this.state.todoData is an array of objects

Comment: Since the todoData is a state, maybe you should check whether the state is updated correctly.

Comment: Produce a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hbjuev), too many questions until you can reproduce an example.

Comment: It got resolved. Its happening because it is not able to set state

Comment: Please give your full code

Answer (score 0):

You are probably keeping objects in todoData that are blank or do not match the format you expected. Must be `[{todoId: "id", todoTitle: "title"}]`. I think the example here will [help](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-curie-n6rp5?file=/src/App.js:729-736) you.